# Invalid url with url_for

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am running into an error using url_for with Python Flask. the error reads:
`MissingSchema: Invalid URL`

Not sure what the issue is. Here is my code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def landing():
    form = forms.OptinForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        requests.get(url_for('indoctrination', email=form.email.data, name=form.first_name.data))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your usage, `url_for` is returning a relative path like `/some/example` . `requests.get` expects a full, absolute path, like `http://example.com/some/path`. You probably want to add your base url in front of the relative path.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but `url_for` can also generate the full URL for you using the `_external` keyword arg like `url_for('indoctrination', ..., _external=True)`. [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for)

Comment: Solved it with the `_external=True`
Thanks guys.

Comment: @jonafato Cool! I've never used `_external` before, but it looks pretty useful! Not sure if it would always work as expected though (e.g. if you're using Flask to serve two different hostnames, `_external` uses `SERVER_NAME` which would be `localhost` or `0.0.0.0` or one of the hostnames or something and you may want to be making this request on the same hostname that the request came in to this route on, in which case you'd want to prepend the `base_url` from the request to the relative `url_for` path).
@freefly0313 Glad you got it working!

Comment: I take that back. I'm running into a different error now. When I submit the form it just hangs and eventually times out.

Comment: @freefly0313 Does the other route your calling complete and return at some point? Is there a more specific error returned by `requests`?

Comment: There is no error that is printed. My web browser just says "Waiting for localhost" until I force reset

Comment: @freefly0313 The flask dev server is single threaded. Making a request to a URL served by flask while handling another request will result in a deadlock (i.e. request A requires that request B finishes, but request B cannot start until request A is done). You should probably call whatever functions you need to directly rather than making an HTTP request to your own flask app inside of itself.

Comment: @jonafato Ah, that is most likely it. +1 for calling directly in Python rather than using an HTTP request.

Comment: Okay. I can call the function directly but how would I pass the data in? `email=form.email.data, name=form.first_name.data`

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to access the function via the URL and through the app. I got it all figured out by rearranging things a bit.

I made `indoctrination` a stand alone function with no view. I called the function on form submit with: `indoctrination(form.email.data, form.first_name.data)`

I then created a seperate view to call the function through the url by using: `indoctrination(request.args.get('email'), request.args.get('name'))`

Thanks again guys!